# Labels not showing up with ax.set_xlabels in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

For some reason my xlabels are not showing up on this graph. I can't figure out why its not working. Any help would be appreciated. My code is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, figsize = (10,6))
plt.hist(result, bins = 100, axes = ax)
ax.axvline(x = 269, color = 'black')
ax.axvline(x = 332, color = 'red', ymax = 0.5)
ax.set_xlabels = 'Obama Electoral College Votes'
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: sorry my bad, i changed it to how i had it. Shouldn't it work this way, since im plotting on the ax?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ax.set_xlabel` ?

Comment: You should use ax.set_xlabel. Did you try this?

Comment: yep i tried ax.set_xlabel and it also didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant assign value to `set_xlabel`,it is a function and require an argument/parameter you can use 
`ax.set_xlabel('Obama Electoral College Votes')`

Comment: Did it help? If yes do upvote and accept the answer, it helps me and the community .

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks alot!